# Can you declare two variables of different types in one statement?

Tags: java, instance-variables

A question from a publicly disclosed exam read "Write a single statement that declares two variables, a and b, and initializes them with the values 7.3 and "Goodbye". "

The answer in the key:

```
double d = 7.3; //or float f = 7.3; (they must have 7.3f, but we will accept 7.3)              
String message = “Goodbye”;
```

Is this a typo? That looks like two statements to me, unless if I have mixed up the definition of a statement.

Comment: Since the answer doesn't declare `a` **or** `b`, I would say it is largely incoherent.

Comment: Have this: `void cheating() { double a = 7.3; String b = "Goodbye"; }` and then all you need to do is to write `cheating();` - a single statement.

Comment: But yes. Those are two statements. Share the publically disclosed final exam with us.

Comment: You are right, that is 2 statements. You *can* put them on one *line*, but it is still two *statements*. The only way to do it in one statement would be: `Object a = 7.3, b = "Goodbye";` Object is the nearest (and only) common type to both values, and autoboxing will wrap `7.3` in a `Double` for us. It is technically the only right answer if you take the question literally.

Comment: I'd say that that's the answer. Unless you make the 7.3 a string value of "7.3". The question doesn't explicitly state that the value of 7.3 can't be a string value. Although it is suggestive of differing underlying types. In which case, Object is the way to go.

Comment: As for definition of a statement, JLS defines [`BlockStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-BlockStatement) as a `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` or a `Statement`, and the first one is defined as `LocalVariableDeclaration ;`, i.e. ending with the `;`. So, those are 2 local variable declaration statements. The Java Language Specification says so, and you can't find a more official definition than that.

Comment: @Andreas the `Serializable` interface is common to both `Double` and `String`.

Comment: It's doesn't say "initialize *to* the value 7.3" but "*with* the value 7.3", so `String a = String.valueOf(7.3), b = "Goodbye";` would also be correct if you're a bit of a language lawyer - although I think @Andreas' suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write a single statement that declares two variables, a and b, and initializes them with the values 7.3 and “Goodbye”. (Choose an appropriate type.)
```

From [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2015/cmsc131/content/exams/midterm1/oldExams/MidtermSpring11.pdf). Based on 'Choose an appropriate type', I'd say:

```
private String a = "7.3", b = "Goodbye";
```

Comment: The answer key is not saying "7.3".

Comment: What is an answer key? And the value of a is still `7.3`, just like the value of b is `Goodbye`, and not `"Goodbye"`

Comment: It's in the question he is asking.

Comment: "The answer in the key" -- Can you help me understand what that means?

Comment: @Erik An answer key is a resource that provides a "canonical" answer to the question in the text, generally at the end of the chapter or book (but sometimes only in the teachers' edition). For example, [Sample Questions And Answer Key](http://www.fldoe.org/accountability/assessments/k-12-student-assessment/history-of-fls-statewide-assessment/fcat-2-0/sample-questions-answer-key.stml).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ah, I never encountered that term before! Thanks!